# How is calculated "24-hour period" for the limitation of Asynchronous Apex Executions

Tags: governorlimits, asynchronous, asyncapexjob

I have a question regarding Execution Governors and Limits for  daily maximum number of asynchronous Apex method executions.
In the [Salesforce documantation](https://developer.salesforce.com/docs/atlas.en-us.apexcode.meta/apexcode/apex_gov_limits.htm) it is written, that the maximum number of asynchronous Apex method executions (batch Apex, future methods, Queueable Apex, and scheduled Apex) per a 24-hour period is 250,000 or the number of user licenses in your org multiplied by 200, whichever is greater.

I'm not sure if this question has been already asked in the community, but if anyone know what is meant by "24-hour period"? How it's calculated? It is depending on your org default Time Zone? Is it fixed( i.e. between 9:30 time on 29 of March and 9:30 time on the 30 of March or is it between 00 o'clock time on 29 of March - 9:30 time on the 30 of March. ) or is a sliding window/rolling period, like is explained in this [post](https://mbwhatsnew.wordpress.com/2017/07/10/when-does-the-salesforce-api-limit-reset/)?
Could you please give more information on this topic?

Answer (score 6):

It's a rolling window. The start of the range is the same as what you would get from `Datetime.now().addHours(-24)`.

Comment: Could you please explain me how it's exactly sliding window? Have ever tested it? Because, when I tried to test  it didn't returned the expected results if it is rolling window. Every day it reset the limits around the same time and this behavior have confused me.

Comment: It resets at the top of the hour, eliminating what you did from 24 hours ago. For example, if during the same hour 24 hours ago you did 10k, then the rolling limit would free up 10k for usage during the current hour.